# How to handle this kind of message in c - conflicting type for 'objectFromFile'

Tags: c, eclipse, file, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04

```
Object* createObject(char *fileName) {
    FILE *fileToObject = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fileToObject == NULL) {
        printf("Failed opening the file , Exiting !\n ");
        return NULL;

    }
    return objectFromFile(fileToObject);
}
//creates vertex
Vertex* createVertex(char *line, Vertex *v) {
    float x, y, z;
    sscanf(line, "%*c %f %f %f", &x, &y, &z);
    v->x = x;
    v->y = y;
    v->z = z;
    return v;
}
//creates face
Face* createFace(char *line, Face *face) {
    char *delimeters = " ";
    char *temp = (char*) calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    temp = strtok(line, delimeters);

    while (temp != NULL) {
        temp = strtok(NULL, delimeters);
        *face->vertex = atoi(temp);
    }
    return face;
}
//creates object
Object* objectFromFile(FILE *file) {
    Object *obj = (Object*) malloc(sizeof(Object));
    if (obj == NULL) {
        printf("Failed allocating memory for object");
        return NULL;
    }
    Vertex *vertexes = (Vertex*) malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    if (obj == NULL) {
        printf("Failed allocating memory for vertex");
        return NULL;
    }
    Face *faces = malloc(sizeof(Face));
    if (obj == NULL) {
        printf("Failed allocating memory for face");
        return NULL;
    }
    obj->numberOfFaces = 0;
    obj->numberOfVertexes = 0;
    char *line = malloc(sizeof(char));
    while (fgets(line, MAX_SIZE, file)) {
        if (line[0] == 'v' && line[1] == ' ') {
            vertexes = (Vertex*) realloc(vertexes,
                    (obj->numberOfVertexes + 1) * sizeof(Vertex));
            if (vertexes == NULL) {
                printf("Failed allocating vertexes");
                return NULL;
            }
            vertexes[obj->numberOfVertexes++] = *createVertex(line, vertexes);
        } else if (line[0] == 'f' && line[1] == ' ') {
            faces = (Face*) realloc(faces,
                    (obj->numberOfFaces + 1) * sizeof(Face));
            if (faces == NULL) {
                printf("Faild allocating faces");
                return NULL;
            }
            createFace(line, faces);
            faces[obj->numberOfFaces++] = *createFace(line, faces);
        }
    }
    obj->vertexes = vertexes;
    obj->faces = faces;
    free(line);
    fclose(file);
    return obj;
}
```

This function creates an object from a file, but as I try to return the value from the function I get this type of message - "conflicting type for 'objectFromFile'. "  I tried finding the error but could not see it. I'm using eclipse environment with gcc compiler, on ubuntu using VM workstation player.
 I would really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a prototype for your functions.

Place this before `createObject`:

```
Object* objectFromFile(FILE *file);
```

This "conflicting type" error is caused by a legacy concept called implicit declaration, wherein all functions returned `int` if they weren't passed an argument.

You can compile with the options `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror` (C11 standard, strict compliance, all and extra warnings, warnings are errors) to catch these mistakes in the future.